# Unable to create positive samples from a limited set of samples for Haar training

Tags: opencv

I am building a Haar classifier. I have a set of 109 positive samples and 3000 negative samples. To increase my number of positive samples (to say 600), I try using the following command:

```
opencv_createsamples -vec out.vec -w 24 -h 24 -bg bg.txt -num 600 -info positives.dat
```

But I get the following error message:

```
positives.dat(109) : parse errorDone. Created 108 samples
```

How can I "force" opencv to produce the 600 samples from those 109 I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencv's default function for creating samples can only create as many as you have in your info file. A

lso, you should know if you use -info as opposed to -img it only resizes them to what you specified as h and w and grayscales all the images. It doesn't actually apply any transforms on them or superimpose them on background images. I'm not entirely sure what the point of the function is really...